# Using "scroll" listener efficiently

Tags: javascript

What I'm trying to achieve:
I want few "scroll" listeners that will work smoothly (As smooth as it can be)

What I have so far works but I have noticed that it is not performing well.
I have good PC but when those functions fire all at once there is huge FPS drop that results in bad user experience (drops to about 1/3 of normal performance which results in slideshow on certain elements).

On page where the problem occurs there are in total 5 "scroll" listeners.
3 of them are pretty basic like:

- watching if i'm scrolling upwards oraz downwards and applying class to element according to direction (show menu when scrolling up)
- checking if element is visible in window and applying class according to it and then don't trigger on same element (triggering css animation).
- again checking if element is visible but this time performs function if it is in window visible and then doesn't fire again (listener is removed when function performs).

and now there are 2 listeners that makes much more on scroll
both of them animate certain element according to how far user scroll from top of page

first one widen certain element when user scrolls into its section

```js
const scaleContainer = () => {
    const container = document.querySelector('#social-posts').parentElement;
    const element = container.parentElement;
    const windowHeight = (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight);
    
    container.style.width = window.getComputedStyle(container).width;
    container.parentElement.style.margin = '0 auto';

    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
        if (window.innerWidth < 767) {
            element.style.width = '100%';
            return;
        }

        const bounding = element.getBoundingClientRect();
        const fromScreenBottom = bounding.top - windowHeight;
        let width = 0;

        if (fromScreenBottom < 0) {
            width = (-(Math.floor(fromScreenBottom)) / 5);
            if (width > 100 || width < 0) {
                return;
            }
        }

        element.style.width = width + '%';
    });
}
ready(scaleContainer);
window.addEventListener('resize', scaleContainer);
```

and the other one checks how far users scrolls and then prepare keyframes for animation function and then animate.
Adding whole class that have all options set will be a pain to read so I will explain briefly what every part that is not defined in this part do.
`this.currentIndex` is the index of element that is currently visible
`this.prevIndex` is the index of previously visible element
`this.options.keyframes` is an array of keyframes that function chooses from to perform animation.
eg:

```js
keyFrames: {
    0: {top: '5%',left: '90%',transform: 'rotate(-38deg)'},
    5: {top: '16%',left: '86%',transform: 'rotate(-36deg)'},
    10: {top: '27%',left: '82%',transform: 'rotate(-33deg)'},
    15: {top: '36%',left: '78%',transform: 'rotate(-30deg)'},
    //...
}
```

`this.options.accordionsCount` is count of element that needs to be taken into account when choosing how many keyframes needs to be used
`this.options.objectContainer` is parent element of whole section.

```js
class TruckAccordions {
    //...

    animateTruck = () => {
        if(this.currentIndex === this.prevIndex || window.innerWidth <= 992) {
            return;
        }

        const previousPercent = Math.floor((100 / this.options.accordionsCount) * (this.prevIndex + 1));
        const percent = Math.floor((100 / this.options.accordionsCount) * (this.currentIndex + 1));
        const objectKeyFrames = Object.entries(this.options.keyFrames);

        let keyFrames = [];

        if (previousPercent < percent) {
            objectKeyFrames.forEach(keyFrame => {
                if ((keyFrame[0] <= percent && keyFrame[0] >= (previousPercent - 5))) {
                    keyFrames.push(keyFrame[1]);
                }
            });
        } else {
            objectKeyFrames.reverse().forEach(keyFrame => {
                if ((keyFrame[0] >= percent && keyFrame[0] <= (previousPercent + 5))) {
                    keyFrames.push(keyFrame[1]);
                }
            });
        }

        const truck = this.options.objectContainer.querySelector('.truck');
        truck.animate(
            keyFrames,
            {
                duration: 1000,
                fill: 'forwards',
                easing: 'ease-in-out'
            }
        );

        this.prevIndex = this.currentIndex;
    }
}

(() => new TruckAccordions())();
```

Comment: Your "const scaleContainer = () => {...};ready(scaleContainer);
window.addEventListener('resize', scaleContainer);" seems to be an issue. With that logic, on each resize a new 'scroll' eventListener will be created. After a while you will have 1000s of scroll eventListeners firing at once.

Comment: That's fair point. I rewrited it so every time scaleContainer() is fired old listener is destroyed and new one created. Unfortunately, the performance problem remained.

Comment: Also. Problem that you are talking about shows when "resize" is performed but when I was testing I haven't triggered resize.